# Should we replace general tags on a question if there is a more specific tag that is more applicable?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, policy

I saw a proposed edit in the review queue that added a `java` tag to an `android` question. The question had nothing to do with Java, but everything to do with Android.

Since the Java tag added no value to the question, I decided to reject the edit, but it had already been approved.

Intuitively it makes sense to me that one should **use the most specific applicable tag for a question**. So rather than tagging your question `microsoft` or `windows` or `visual-studio`, tag it `visual-studio-2013`.

If the principle is sound, then it behooves us to edit questions to replace general tags where a more specific tag is applicable.

However, I saw nothing to guide users to this kind of behaviour in the tag FAQ section.

It also occurs to me that people might tend to subscribe to only very general tags. I have insufficient information to decide whether the principle is sound or not.

Is there existing policy that addresses this question? If not, are there any other pros and cons I missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no.

You should use specific tags for your question that fit. But you can use more general tags also, **if they fit**.

Example: Having those 2 tags in your question

[sql](/questions/tagged/sql) [sql-server-2008](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008)

is totally appropriate if you ask for help on a SQL-Server query.

#### But inappropriate tags should be removed from a question!

Why do we have tags? So we can better find questions. Tags that help finding a questions are fine, but they must fit the question.

Comment: This answers my question, and it also doesn't. How does one judge the appropriateness of a tag? Is it OK to tag `sql-server` and `sql-server-2008` for a question about sql that uses syntax only available in 2008?

Comment: @GustavBertram, I suspect that in that case, it is just fine.  The questioner is using 2008, but the problem may not have anything to do with 2008-syntax.  Also all answerers knows they may use 2008 syntax, but perhaps not 2012 features.  The "sql-server" tag is necessary to reach the broader community.

Comment: @GustavBertram: A asker may not know if the 2008 syntax is relevant. It's always best to tag as specific as possible and add more general tags that really fit too.

Comment: The "necessary to reach the broader community" sounds like appropriate policy that echos "You are replacing obscure or difficult to understand tags with well-known and popular tags that are appropriate for the question" from the tag FAQ.